# Faster way to enter Markdown in IJulia Notebook

Tags: julia, jupyter, ijulia-notebook

To enter Markdown in IJulia Notebook, I am currently using `Esc` to get to Command Mode and then `Alt Gr` and `M` to change the cell to Markdown. This feels cumbersome. Is there a faster way? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be sufficient to just do `Esc` `M`.